# how to display an alert in an Onclick event after dom is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, onclicklistener

I am stuck with a displaying a simple `alert`. I have a filter button which is created dynamically using jQuery. With this code I am getting alerts randomly. I am not sure why this is happening?

Please help me to get an `alert` on each `li` click instead of random alerts.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $('#game-categories ul li').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      alert("woohoo working");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="game-categories">
  <div class="ais-RefinementList">
    <ul class="ais-RefinementList-list ais-refinement-list--list">
      <li class="ais-RefinementList-item ais-refinement-list--item">
        <div><span><img src="https://staging.roger.com/wp-content/themes/roger-theme/img/icons/u/Slots.svg"></span><br> Slots</div>
      </li>
      <li class="ais-RefinementList-item ais-refinement-list--item">
        <div><span><img src="https://staging.roger.com/wp-content/themes/roger-theme/img/icons/u/Games.svg"></span><br> Games</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I am getting alerts randomly"* - are you?  What do you mean by "randomly"?  There's nothing in your code that suggest "random" alerts.

Comment: Your code, which I placed in an executable snippet, works fine. If you're creating elements dynamically it sounds like this is possibly an event delegation problem. However in that case it would work, or it would not. There would be nothing 'random' about it.

Comment: i will get the alert in my first click. then may be after my 5th or 6th click. or may be on 3rd click. that is what i meant by randomly

Answer (score -1):

You could do with `document.ready` for dom load complete.And use  `$('#game-categories ul li').on('click'` on dynamically loaded element as well as clicked target li

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#game-categories ul li').on('click', function() {
      alert("woohoo working");
      console.log($(this).find('img').attr('src'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="game-categories">
  <div class="ais-RefinementList">
    <ul class="ais-RefinementList-list ais-refinement-list--list">
      <li class="ais-RefinementList-item ais-refinement-list--item">
        <div><span><img src="https://staging.roger.com/wp-content/themes/roger-theme/img/icons/u/Slots.svg"></span><br> Slots</div>
      </li>
      <li class="ais-RefinementList-item ais-refinement-list--item">
        <div><span><img src="https://staging.roger.com/wp-content/themes/roger-theme/img/icons/u/Games.svg"></span><br> Games</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```